# Nginx 504 Bad Gateway Error

Tags: java, http, nginx, amazon-web-services

I have a java servlet environment that intentionally keeps an http connection open and sending data to a client.
This connection is getting dropped after 50 seconds, I tried different settings in the nginx.conf file but none of those have worked.

I'm getting this error.

upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: {Some IP}, server: , request: "GET /{some path} HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "sadfdsa.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com"

Comment: What is your ELB's connection timeout?

Comment: Thats one of the things I already tried, I increased it to 120 seconds from 60 which was the default but still nothing.

Comment: Did you check nginx's timeout parameters? proxy_read_timeout, proxy_send_timeout those are default set to 60s.

Comment: yeah actually that's the solution that worked but I missed updating the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

```
Syntax:     proxy_send_timeout time;
Default:    proxy_send_timeout 60s;
Context:    http, server, location
The timeout is set only between two successive write operations, not for the transmission of the whole request.

Syntax:     proxy_read_timeout time;
Default:    proxy_read_timeout 60s;
Context:    http, server, location
The timeout is set only between two successive read operations, not for the transmission of the whole response.
```

Editing those obviously helped the asker.